# How can I make navigation between scenes inside same tabbar in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, tabbarios

I`m using Navigator in a ios react-native app, and I have a Tabbar. But one of the tabs has a view that might navigate to anothe view inside the same tab. How can I do this?

I`ve tried to render 2 tabbar:

```
if(this.props.route.name === 'visualizarEstabelecimento') {
    return(<MainEstabelecimentoView navigator={this.props.navigator} route={this.props.route}/>);         
  }
  else {
    return(<MainPrincipalView navigator={this.props.navigator} route={this.props.route}/>);
  }
```

but the tabbar is rendered with the transition of the view...

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use react-native-scrollable-tab-view. It is purely written in JavaScript. I am using it in my Android app.

Comment: Make sense. But if i have 10 pages so i need to add 10 screens on scrollview, if i used navigator instead of this then i don't need to add 10 pages on a screen. So technically what is better???

Comment: Actually it depends on your UI. If you have 10 tabs than I recommend not to use tabbar. In UX perspective tabbar is best for 2 to 5 tabs only.